# How Use Xpath resolve-uri

Tags: xpath

I want  get a url form html page with xpath .

i used the `//*[@id="main"]/table/tr[2]/td[3]/a/@href`

its return url like this `/nevesta/yulia`

i want add Base URI to url like this `http//mydomain.ru/nevesta/yulia`

after searching i found out , resolve-uri do that , but Unfortunately i can't find any example for this.

Answer (score 1):

```
concat(base-uri(.), data(//*[@id="main"]/table/tr[2]/td[3]/a/@href))
```

Comment: Is this a question or an answer? It sounds like a question ;)

Comment: i am asking because I don't have the actual input to test this into.

Comment: I have created a sample to test the code, and have modified my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It returns the Base URI of the document/node as defined in [XML Base](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlbase/). There are some examples for using it on [XQueryFunctions.com](http://www.xqueryfunctions.com/xq/fn_base-uri.html). Quoting from the linked page above:

> If `$arg` is an element, the function returns the value of its `xml:base` attribute, if any, or the `xml:base` attribute of its nearest ancestor. If no `xml:base` attributes appear among its ancestors, it defaults to the base URI of the document node.

In other words: this function returns a sequence of base URIs of the nearest ancestor; if there isn't defined any, the one of the document (which you seem to be after).

But please be aware that this is an **XPath 2.0 only function** (and thus also XQuery, if course) and not available in XPath 1.0!